# A sequence defined by $(2^n-1)\,a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k\,a_{n-k}\,(k+1)^{-1}$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

Let $a_n$ be the sequence of rational numbers defined by the recurrence
$$a_0=1,\quad\left(2^n-1\right)a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{\small\binom n k}\frac{a_{n-k}}{k+1}.\tag1$$
It begins
$$\small1,\,\frac12,\,\frac5{18},\,\frac16,\,\frac{143}{1350},\,\frac{19}{270},\,\frac{1153}{23814},\,\frac{583}{17010},\,...\tag2$$
and is apparently related to [$\texttt{A272755}$](https://oeis.org/A272755) and the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function).

It appears that the following simpler identity holds:
$$a_n\stackrel{\small\color{silver}?}=\sum_{k=0}^n{\small\binom n k}\,(-1)^k\,a_k.\tag3$$
How can we prove it?

(Note that $(3)$ could not be used as a definition of $a_n$ because the term $a_n$ is canceled for even $n$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we call $f(x)=\sum \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$, then the first recursion is equivalent to $$f(2x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}f(x).$$
In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06487.pdf) (page 5), one can see that $f(x)=e^{x/2}\hat{\text{up}}(\frac{ix}{4\pi}),$ where $$\hat{\text{up}}(x)=\prod _{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x/2^n)}{\pi x/2^n}.$$
notice that $\hat{\text{up}}(x)$ is an even function and so

$$f(-x)e^x=e^{x/2}\hat{\text{up}}(\frac{ix}{4\pi})=f(x),$$
and so checking at the coefficient of $x^n$ on that equation, we get that
$$\sum _{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^ka_k=a_n.$$

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I've seen this paper by J. Arias de Reyna before, but forgot about that part (curiously, he proves one of my conjectures in the paper). Do you think we can find a discrete arithmetic or combinatorial proof that doesn't go through the Fabius and Rvachev functions and their Fourier transforms?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov You are welcome. I tried a bit using just the recursion but failed. I can't think of any combinatorial description, do you know if there is any? Maybe that way we can think of  an inclusion-exclusion argument.